# Setting ulimit stack size in Terraform's aws_ecs_task_definition resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I need to increase the stack size in my ECS tasks.

Does [`aws_ecs_task_definition`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_task_definition.html) support ulimit stack size? If it does whats the syntax?

Answer (score 6):

`ulimit` and other resource limits can be set in the container definitions for each container in a task. This is shown in the [AWS User Guide for ECS task definitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_limits) and is analogous to [`--ulimit` in the `docker run` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-ulimits-in-container---ulimit).

To set a ulimit for your container in a task definition you'll want something like the following for your container definitions:

```
[
  {
    "name": "first",
    "image": "service-first",
    "cpu": 10,
    "memory": 512,
    "essential": true,
    "ulimits": [
      {
        "name": "stack",
        "softLimit": 8192,
        "hardLimit": 16384
      }
    ]
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 80,
        "hostPort": 80
      }
    ]
  }
]
```